# Sort by matching field

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

Supposing I have a file F:

```
hi xb 9 test
hi xc 8 test
hi xa 7 test
```

I need to sort the lines of this file. But I have two ways I want to sort them.

Method 1: Sort by column.
How do I sort the lines by lets say column 2 (xb, xc, xa) or say column 3 (8, 9, 7)?

Expected output if sorted by column 2:

```
hi xa 7 test
hi xb 9 test
hi xc 8 test
```

Method 2: Sort by the number on column 3.
What is the regex I need to capture the number on column 3?

Expected output:

```
hi xa 7 test
hi xc 8 test
hi xb 9 test
```

Comment: Please ask just one question at the time. Also, it is not clear what you want in Method 1. Add a desired output as well. Method 2 is easy, just do some research and I am sure you'll find tons of examples.

Comment: I thought it would be wasteful to ask two questions. So combined them into one. They are also both quite similar.

Comment: `sort -k2,2 file` and `sort -nk3,3 file`